# An object field returns the object itself, not an instance stored in the field

Tags: c++

(Not sure if this title is the best description...)

Hi all. I need a help with the following code. In `process` function, I want `cc` and `cc_sub` (which is obtained as a field in `cc`) to show different contents (as they are originally made so) but they show the same. `Storage` instances are made in `makeObj` function. Could someone tell me what's wrong and how to work this around? Thank you.

```
Int process(const Storage cc) {
    Storage cc_sub = (Storage&) cc.data;  // Here
    cout << ... << endl;         // Contents from cc and cc_sub are the same though they are not supposed to be.
}

class Storage {
    public:
        Storage() {
            this->data = NULL;
        }
        Storage(const Storage& obj) { //Copy Constructor. Result is the same even if I removed this entire clause.
            this->data = obj.data;
        }
        void* data;
        void setData(Storage dPtr) {
            this->data = &dPtr;
        }
};

Storage makeObj(std::string* s) { // I want to keep the return value as value instead of pointer, 
                       // since when it returns pointer the values pointed by reference behaved unexpectedly (guess it's because of temporary object type of error)... 
    Storage cc;
    :
    cc.setData(makeObj(&subString)); 
    return cc;
    :
}
```

Comment: That `this->data = &dPtr;` looks suspicious to me.  Isn't it setting a pointer to a temporary object (that will get destroyed when the function returns, making the pointer point to gawd-knows-what)?

Comment: Thanks. Honestly I don't understand yet. And besides that, even if so, it still seems not to explain why 2 different instances show the same contents...

Comment: Couldn't really say til you resolve the UB.  Once you get to the point where you're using pointers to stuff that no longer technically exists, *anything* can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The odd behavior you're seeing is due to manipulating temporary `Storage` variables, both within `setData` and `makeObj`. The outcome of such manipulation is undefined in C++.

Try the following:

```
void process(const Storage cc) {
    Storage cc_sub = *((Storage*)cc.data);
    cout << ... << endl;
}

class Storage {
    public:
        Storage() {
            this->data = NULL;
        }

        Storage(const Storage& obj) {
            this->data = obj.data;
        }
        void* data;
        void setData(Storage* dPtr) {
            this->data = dPtr;
        }
};

Storage* makeObj(std::string* s) {
    // Allocate memory on the heap so that cc lives beyond this function call
    Storage* cc = new Storage;
    :
    // Populate the sub-storage with a heap-allocated variable
    cc->setData(makeObj(&subString));
    return cc;
}
```

Note, the code as currently written `makeObj` will cause a stack overflow if called as it has no way of ending its recursion...

To cHao's suggestion here's a more complete program using `shared_ptr` (Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 version - you may need to change `#include <memory>` and/or `std::tr1::shared_ptr` depending on your compiler). I've changed the type of the data from `void*` to `Storage` (`shared_ptr`) and added a string member to better show the differences:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr1;

class Storage {
    public:
        Storage() {
        }
        Storage(const Storage& obj) {
            this->data = obj.data;
        }
    string s;
    shared_ptr<Storage> data;
        void setData(shared_ptr<Storage> dPtr) {
            this->data = dPtr;
        }
};

void process(const shared_ptr<Storage> cc) {
    shared_ptr<Storage> cc_sub = cc.get()->data;
    cout << "Parent string: " << cc.get()->s << endl << 
            "Child string: " << cc_sub.get()->s << endl;
    cout << "Parent data pointer: " << cc.get()->data << endl << 
            "Child data pointer: " << cc_sub.get()->data << endl;
}

shared_ptr<Storage> makeObj(string* s) {
    shared_ptr<Storage> cc(new Storage);
    if (s->length() != 0) {
        string subString = s->substr(0, s->length()-1);
        cc->s = subString;
        cc->setData(makeObj(&subString));
    }

    return cc;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string s = "hello";
    shared_ptr<Storage> storage = makeObj(&s);
    process(storage);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I should've mentioned (now I modified original question) that I want to return value from `makeObj` not pointer...

Comment: You could conceivably return a value from `makeObj` -- you just need to make sure your copy constructor and/or `setData` make a copy of `*data` (the value, not just the pointer) as well, and that your destructor deletes `data`.  I could see that causing a bunch of unnecessary copies, though... Better would be to use and return `shared_ptr`s and let the runtime handle the dirty details.

Comment: In order to do this the `Storage` copy constructor would need to recurse down the hierarchical structure built up by `makeObj`. This would lead to a more complex solution than the above. Does this code not work for you?

Comment: @Matthew Murdoch thanks, I'm trying your solution (not `shared_ptr` one, and getting rid of the errors that start to occur in another parts). May take awhile to apply and fully understand what you guys kindly suggest here.

Answer (score 0):

Before I start: what are you trying to achieve with the `(Storage &)` cast? I don't think I know the syntax. I'll try to use the closest estimate of what I *think* you're doing.

Edit: this part of my answer is obsolete, see comments below.

> When you do this:
>
> ```
> Storage cc_sub = *(Storage *) cc.data;
> ```
>
> you are taking the pointer `cc.data`, casting it to `Storage` and
>   assigning it to the variable cc_sub. Copy constructor has little to do
>   with this. Try overriding the assignment operator and see if that
>   helps. Or try:
>
> ```
> Storage cc_sub(*(Storage*) cc.data);
> ```
>
> to make an explicit copy constructor call.

If it still doesn't help it may have to do with your program logic, as I see you are referencing your `Storage` instances recursively with the `data` member... (After all, if your `cc.data` points to `cc`, then the behavior is correct, no?)

Comment: `Storage cc_sub = *((Storage*) cc.data);` **would** call the copy constructor rather than the assignment operator

Comment: Hmmm you mean we'd need `explicit` to prevent that?

Comment: No, I just mean that when you declare a variable and assign it in the same statement this compiles to a call to the copy constructor (rather than a call to the default constructor and then the assignment operator).

Comment: Got it, thanks. (Using `explicit` when declaring the copy constructor doesn't even compile with that assignment...)